# All torrents time out; no firewall activated

Tags: router, debian, bittorrent

I'm having trouble with torrents. I use transmission and all my trackers give the errors "peer list request timed out" and "tracker did not respond". I query if the port is open (Edit > Preferences > Network > Test port) and after a long while it says it's closed, although I have it forwarded and triggered on my router; I even set my computer to be a DMZ. Any ideas?

I use Debian squeeze and transmission 2.03.

Comment: Maybe your debian has its own firewall? Can you ping out to the tracker?

Comment: I can, I've tried most of them already. As far as I know I did not install any firewall on my Debian. I've checked on my installed programs on synaptic

Comment: So you can ping the tracker directly, but your "transmission" can't see the tracker? This sounds like a firewall issue. Note: even if you don't have firewall front-end GUI, debian still comes with iptables and that is to my knowledge is the firewall and may blocked transmission. I don't use debian so I can't say for sure.